# Convert output of string to a number value

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
Call.Direction CallDir = details.dir;
```

and the output is either `In` or `out`.

my question how can I convert the output to be as follow:

- if CallDir value is In ===> display 0
- if CallDir value is Out ===> display 1

Comment: What's `Call.Direction`; an `enum`? If so, please show its definition.

Comment: Yes it is an enum, it is used for the direction of a call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so if you wanted to return a different value based on the `enum`, just do this:

```
return CallDir == Call.Direction.In ? 0 : 1;
```

However, if what you're saying is `details.dir` is a string of `In` or `Out` and you need to get that into an `enum`, then do this:

```
Call.Direction CallDir;
if (!enum.TryParse<Call.Direction>(details.dir, out CallDir))
{
    // set it to some default value because it failed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Michael said, if your `enum` is defined with the appropriate values, you can simply cast it to an `int`.

```
enum CallDirection { In = 0, Out = 1 }

var dir = CallDirection.In;

Console.Write((int)dir); // "0"
```